# How to delete all Items from List by parentId

Tags: c#, list

I have a Simple CRUD application with categories and phones,
For single delete phone from *List* i uses:

```
var arrayPhones = new List<Phone>();
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"d:/phones.json"))
        {
            var strPhones = file.ReadToEnd();
            arrayPhones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Phone>>(strPhones);


            var currentPhone = arrayPhones.Where(p => p.Id == phone.Id).SingleOrDefault();
            arrayPhones.Remove(currentPhone);
        }
```

Now i tring delete *Category* and all *Phones* of this category, model of my Phone:

```
 public class Phone
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parentId")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("caption")]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("imgUrl")]
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
```

How i can delete all phones of category?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: What's `category` here?

Comment: @MaheshChand  i safe my category in another file, and delete method of delete category look like single delete phone method. It works, I just have trouble with deleting all phones. Thnx for you comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple records, select which are not to be removed and assign to list,

```
arrayPhones = arrayPhones.Where(p => p.Id != phone.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: it's awesome solution, thnx

Answer (score 2):

Seems some info is missing. How is your Category class defined? How does your Phone class reference the Category?

Say if Phone has a prop CategoryId, it would be something like:

```
var phonesOfThisCategory = arrayPhones.Where(p => p.CategoryId == category.Id);

foreach(var aPhone in phonesOfThisCategory)
{
    arrayPhones.Remove(aPhone);
}
```

Comment: I done it, thank you for your answer, parentId in Phone = categoryId,

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method